# If an object or particle were to travel faster than the speed of light, how would I measure it?

Tags: velocity, measurements, faster-than-light, tachyon

How would I measure the speed of particle hypothetically traveling faster than light?
Is there any kind of camera that could detect this?

Comment: People have tried a variety of techniques for detecting tachyons. For a summary, see section 4.7.3 of my SR book, http://lightandmatter.com/sr/

Answer (score 1):

One would literally just measure the speed of this particle the same as you'd measure the speed of any other particle. It's change in distance over change in time. (This is all theoretical, obviously, because particles *don't* travel faster than the speed of light.)

Interestingly enough, there is a camera. At a trillion frames per second, it can watch light moving. The camera was built by [MIT's media lab](http://web.media.mit.edu/~raskar/trillionfps/). They call it [femto-photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femto-photography). The leader of the team, Ramesh Raskar, gave a TED talk, which includes a video of the camera at work. It's really interesting - watch it [here](https://www.ted.com/talks/ramesh_raskar_a_camera_that_takes_one_trillion_frames_per_second).

Comment: Direct measurement of time and distance is usually referred to as "time of flight" (often abbreviated "TOF"), BTW. Because the speed of light is about 1 foot-per-nanosecond and nanosecond timing of particle detector elements is pretty easy, it is common in the particle world to make only slightly crude TOF measurements on the scale of a couple of meters. Reasonably fine TOF measurements can be made on the scale of ten meters. Precision work requires rather longer distance scales.

Comment: Just to be retro-pedantic, this camera does not actually take contiguous frames, and cannot "watch" a single wavefront of light moving. It operates by accumulating millions of repeated "showings", using similar light pulses and a slowly advancing time offset to create the illusion of following a single pulse.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you could. I see this as a problem of resolution. Just as we can't know for a fact that electrons are fundamental, we can't see anything smaller than an electron because an electron is the smallest thing we know of that we can use to 'see' small things, we can't really know for certain that nothing can travel faster than light, since light is the fastest thing we know of that we can use to 'see' a thing. We don't really see the thing, just it's interactions with things around it whether that be via light waves, or sound waves, or whatever.

If we were blind, and could only sense things by sound, or sonar, would we know that there are things that travel faster than sound? Our senses would tell us no. Even the sound waves from a supersonic jet only travel at the speed of sound. We need something much faster than an object whose speed is being measured in order to measure that object's speed.

And that fast camera? Even though it can show light moving, is sensitive only to the light wave which has as an upper limit the speed of light, so it would only be able to confirm that light moves at the speed of light.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring any experiment that involves clock synchronization. But it is not even that complex. Shoot a hypothetical tachyon at a far away detector and have that detector light up upon receipt. You know the speed of the return light, and can hence measure the speed of the tachyon.

Comment: Is it not possible that dark matter is matter traveling faster than the speed of light? something traveling faster than the speed of light would be exceedingly hard to detect except for a single instance. If you don't know it's there, it would look noise since you would never detect that bit of matter again.

Comment: I think there are several flaws in your logic. For instance, we would have no problem measuring the speed of a supersonic object using only sound. Observer A says "it passed overhead at T1" and observer B says "it passed overhead at T2". It's simple math to determine the speed. Bringing dark matter into this just confuses the subject.